# Facebook connect session

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

I am using facebook connect on my site. I use some code to retrive data from facebook like Profile Information, Friends list etc.

My session will not expire until I close the browser manualy.

What code should I use on my logout page so that the session will expire automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the FB Javascript library included (like this):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
</script>
```

you can use `FB.logout()`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="FB.logout();return false;">Logout</a>
```

Note that this will log out the user from FB Connect *and* Facebook.